# How to calculate distance between 2 longitudes at any coordinate? Can we assume earth to be a sphere?

Tags: java, android, math, gps, geolocation

I thought that this one would be easy to find on net but seems its not.

I want to know the distance between 2 consecutive longitudes at a given latitude value. That is to measure with a rope keeping it parallel to equator. I can calculate it by simple geometry assuming earth to be  a proper sphere. But will that assumption be acceptable?Please give an idea about the  error margin in that assumption. Or,

Please let me know a mathematical formula or a Java/Android code  to calculate it.

Thanks.

EDIT: Thanks for your responses, it seems to have erupted a mini storm . Please read my comment to David below for clarity

EDIT2: The debate is will the great circle distance (found by haversine formula) and the "rope" distance be the same? According to me it should be. As the great circle distance is the shortest distance between to 2 points, and in the case of rope distance i restrict myself to move along the same latitude from one point to another, which I think is the shortest distance. Isnt it?

EDIT3: I was wrong. After visualizing it a bit I realize that the great circle distance will not be the same as the longitudinal separation at a latitude ("rope" distance"). Both would be same only if the latitude happens to be the equator. What David has been saying. So yes no correct answers yet. For my case I would assume the earth to be a sphere, I would accept Laune's answer in some time as he/she has partially answered my question. Still would be really keen to know if there is way to get a correct calculation.Also, please go through the link given by Byzantine Failure (wats with the name??) It talks about how to create a stored procedure and and query for such problems, really helpful!! Thanks for all your responses!

Comment: When you say "parallel to the equator", do you mean "along the line of latitude"?  Or do you mean the great circle distance between two points of the same latitude?  It's not the same thing.

Comment: Do you realy mean "along a line of latitude" Near the pole sit is more obious that this is not the shortest connection betwwen two points.

Comment: Hi @David,

Will it not be the same? That is the "great circle" distance and the "rope" distance? If I'm correct the the great circle distance is the shortest distance between 2 points, but if i restrict myself moving along the same latitude , wont that be the same thing, or could there be an even shorter distance?

Comment: No, it won't be the same.  A line of latitude is not a great circle (with the exception of the equator), so your distance along a line of latitude can be much greater than the shortest distance between two points.  Get yourself a globe and a piece of string, and have a play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoid

For everyday purposes, you can use the spheric model. Geoid deformation starts in the higher latitudes, so unless you are into something very accurate, scientific or polar travel, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The distance usually used in situation of geolocations is [haversine distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). This is basically an approach of the real distance in earth's surface since it is the distance of two points lying on a sphere having the average radius of earth.

Anyway there are many implementations in Java if you search for them.

Edit: 
In this case there isn't any real difference if the two points have some of their coordinates the same or not (if they have them both different).